# EventEmitter subcriber subcribes multiple times with only one emit

Tags: angular, subscription, eventemitter, emit, subscriber

I had a customService using EventEmitter like below. My problem is that every time I emit the value, the subcription in other component is called several times, looks like it emit multiple times. Is this expected behavior? How to prevent it?

The service is a singleton and I do not call emitValidation multiple times.

```
@Injectable()
export class customService {
    isValidation: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    emitValidation (data) {
        this.isValidation.emit(data);
    }

}
```

Subscription in component:

```
subVar: Subscription;
ngOnInit() {
    this.subVar = this.customService.isValidation
        .subscribe( data => {
            //Do stuff
            //Call multiple times here
        }
    });
}
ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subVar) {
      this.subVar.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Call in another component:

```
this.contactService.emitValidation(0);
```

Comment: One reason may be how your service is applied and linked to the DOM/view. A DOM refresh may cause multiple calls to your code ...

Comment: I have tried to add a static variable in my component(counter - increase on constructor and decrease on onDestroy) to count how many instances of my component are in the DOM. But it still returns 1.

Comment: @XichTop Please share the code of another component, how is it called?

Comment: @NarenMurali It just calls a function in the services that I have added in the end of my question.

Comment: @XichTop Please replicate the issue in a stackblitz and share!

Comment: @XichTop, `EventEmitters` are used for components with `@Output()`, it shouldn't be used in a service... for that, use a proper `Subject`

Comment: @NarenMurali, It works on stackblitz but didn't work in my projects :((
https://angular-ivy-77rroj.stackblitz.io

Comment: @Andres2142, i have tried to use BehaviorSubject in stead of Eventemitter but it still got the same issue.